# ¿Como ejecutar una misma función en un for php?

Tags: php7, bucle-for, codeigniter-3

Tengo 2 métodos, en el primero traigo múltiples base de datos, las recorro con un `ciclo for` para almacenar una a una en un arreglo y de esta manera pasarla al segundo método el cual hará el proceso de conectarse a la base de datos, traer la información recorrerla y descargar en un archivo `excel`.

**EL PROBLEMA**

En el momento cuento con 3 conexiones, pero al momento de ejecutar el segundo método que hace casi todo el proceso solo descarga un archivo de `excel`, es como si el primer `ciclo for` que tiene las 3 conexiones no ejecutara 3 veces el mismo método, ¿porque sucede esto?

**CODIGO**

```
// Metodo que ejecuto directamente
public function index()
    {       
        $resp = $this->Welcome_model->getClinicas();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($resp); $i++):
            $data[$i] = [
                    'host'   => $resp[$i]->cli_host,
                    'dbname' => $resp[$i]->cli_dbname,
                    'user'   => $resp[$i]->cli_user,
                    'pass'   => $resp[$i]->cli_pass,
                    'port'   => $resp[$i]->cli_port,
                    'driver' => $resp[$i]->cli_driver,
            ];


            $this->executeFile($data[$i], $resp[$i]->rep_query, $resp[$i]->rep_nombre);         
        endfor;
    }

public function executeFile($data, $query, $nombre){
            $this->load->library('conexion');
            $this->conexion->connect($data);

            $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $columns = array_keys($result[0]);
      // Starting the PHPExcel library
        $this->load->library('excel');
        //$this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory');

        $this->excel = new PHPExcel();
        $this->excel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // Field names in the first row
        $fields = $columns;//$query->list_fields();
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $field);
            $col++;
        }

        // Fetching the table data
        $row = 2;
        foreach($result as $data)
        {
            $col = 0;
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data[$field]);
                $col++;
            }

            $row++;
        }

        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');

        // Sending headers to force the user to download the file
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$nombre.'.xls');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
```

Comment: Tengo entendido que no podes forzar la descarga de varios archivos en un mismo request. Por eso te descarga uno solo. Una opción sería armar un zip con los 3 archivos excel y solo descargar el zip. Sino acá hay una técnica con iframes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45937933/1095101

Comment: Es lo que dice @azeós una petición, un archivo.

Comment: Si quieres descargar más de un archivo por pulsación debes [hacer uso de javascript y convertir el resultado de peticiones xhr a blobs para forzar su descarga (en este enlace te dejo un ejemplo)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228902/problema-de-compatibilidad-en-navegadores-de-jquey-para-descargar-pdf/229000#229000). Por norma general no puedes forzar la descarga de más de un archivo desde una única petición HTTP.

Comment: @OscarGarcia, muchas gracias por la respuesta, la verdad no sabia que no se puede ejecutar multiples descargas forzadas a travez de una sola peticion; buen dato, un saludo. :D