# Unificar dos documentos PDF que recibo de un servicio

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos botones de descarga que llaman a un servicio para descargar un documento cada uno, como ambos documentos son necesarios descargarlos siempre quiero saber si es posible unificar ambos documentos en una sola acción. Este es el código que utilizo para la descarga:

```
case "document":

        // Call PM WS
        $data = $PMWShandler->getDocument(
            $_GET["productor"],
            $_GET["docId"],
            $_GET["source"],
            $_GET["type"],
            $_GET["format"]
        );
        switch ($_GET["type"]) {
            case "SO":
                $name = "Solicitud";
                break;
            case "CP":
                $name = "Condiciones-Particulares";
                break;

            case "CG":
                $name = "Condiciones-generales";
                break;

            case "REC":
                $name = "Recibo";
                break;
        }

        $decoded = base64_decode( $data['contenidoFichero'] );
        $file = $name.'-'.$_GET["docId"] . '.pdf';
        $r = file_put_contents($file, $decoded);

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file) );
            readfile($file);
            unlink($file);
        }
```

EDIT** Añado la forma en que llamo a la descarga de documentos:
Mediante un form HTML paso los parámetros que sean para pasarlo a la función PHP

```
<div class="col-12">
   <form id="quote-download-form" action="/download" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="docId" class="docId" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="productor" class="productor" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="source" class="source" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="type" class="type" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="format" class="format" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="downloadType" class="downloadType" value="document">
   <input type="submit" id="quote-download-policy-request" class="quote-download-policy-request"  value="{!! __('text.download') !!}">
   </form>
</div>
```

La idea sería unificar dos de los case en una sola llamada ¿es posible?

Comment: ¿Quieres concatenar ambos PDF en un único PDF o que el usuario se descargue ambos PDFs de manera independiente en su PC?

Comment: Además, sería interesante ver cómo enlazas el botón HTML a este código PHP, para poder indicarte cómo solicitar varios documentos (en vez de uno) y/o conseguir la descarga de los dos documentos en paralelo o uno único concatenado (según lo que decidas hacer).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Lo ideal sería que al pulsar el botón se descargasen los dos archivos, primero uno y luego el otro. Edito la entrada para mostrar el botón HTML y explicar su funcionamiento.

Comment: Has agregado el texto *Mediante un form HTML paso los parámetros que sean para pasarlo a la función PHP*, y luego la pregunta *La idea sería unificar dos de los case en una sola llamada*. ¿Qué dos cases? ¿Cómo indicarías al PHP qué dos cases quieres, quiere o necesita el usuario?

Comment: @OscarGarcia te explico como funciona completamente, hay 4 botones diferentes en la web que corresponden a cada case, cada form pasa la info necesaria la función PHP para generar la descarga, para mi lo ideal sería que al pulsar un solo botón de descarga se descarguen los dos documentos de los case "CP" y "CG" de forma separada, pero si esto es mucho lío no vería mal unificar los dos PDF en un solo documento.

Comment: Si quieres hacer las modificaciones mínimas, una solución es enviar dos formularios a dos iframes diferentes, lo que provocará la descarga de cada archivo. También [puedes simular esa funcionalidad con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228902/problema-de-compatibilidad-en-navegadores-de-jquey-para-descargar-pdf/229000#229000). Si quieres agregar soporte para descargar más de un archivo sin usar iframes, y en una única petición HTTP, entonces tendrás que cambiar el código PHP para poder recibir más de un `type`, en los datos devueltos y agregar bastante código javascript.

Comment: ¿Has realizado alguna vez el envío de un formulario a un `iframe` en vez de al marco/página principal? Si no lo has hecho dímelo y te redacto una respuesta con un ejemplo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia no la verdad que nunca he hecho algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes conseguir que se descarguen múltiples archivos sin hacer uso de [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) y/o [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) mediante el envío de un formulario al interior de un `<iframe>` (puede estar oculto).

Debes crear un `<iframe>` por cada archivo que quieras descargar en paralelo y configurar el atributo `target` de cada formulario para que apunte a un `iframe` diferente.

A continuación te muestro un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```js
boton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  /* Enviamos los dos formularios */
  formulario1.submit();
  formulario2.submit();
});
```

```css
iframe {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 2px
}
```

```html
<iframe name="iframe1" sandbox="allow-downloads"></iframe>
<iframe name="iframe2" sandbox="allow-downloads"></iframe>

<form id="formulario1" method="get"
  action="https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/refs/tags/v6.5.3.zip"
  target="iframe1">
</form>
<form id="formulario2" method="get"
  action="https://github.com/angular/angular.js/archive/refs/tags/v1.8.2.zip"
  target="iframe2">
</form>

<button id="boton">Pulsa aquí para descargar dos archivos a la vez</button>
```

Este código no funcionará en stackoverflow por la restricción del entorno de prueba aislado (sandbox), por lo que te enlazo un lugar donde puedes probarlo correctamente:

- https://codepen.io/OscarGarcia/pen/NWaZyPq

Ten en cuenta que el navegador no te permitirá la descarga de múltiples archivos con una única pulsación, por lo que te mostrará una advertencia:

[image: Autorización para descargas múltiples]

Una vez que permitas este tipo de descargas la página estará autorizada a hacerlas hasta que revoques la autorización. La forma de hacerlo depende de cada navegador.

Verás que aparece un icono en la barra de direcciones indicando que se está haciendo uso de ese privilegio especial:

[image: Icono de permiso de descarga múltiple]

Pulsando en ese icono puedes autorizar o rechazar este privilegio y también gestionar los permisos de todos los sitios web. Es posible que haya navegadores que no muestren este icono.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Voy a probar esta forma parece bastante sencilla de aplicar! Si finalmente tengo que hacer algo diferente te lo comentaré para editar la respuesta.

Comment: Suerte con las modificaciones. Te he propuesto esta solución porque es la que menos modificaciones necesitas en tu código PHP para que funcione (y las modificaciones en la página son mínimas). Las otras soluciones implican modificaciones el código PHP.